# Using keycloak in a spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

in a project for my internship I have a spring boot application that manages some products, orders, and users.

I chose to use keycloak for authentication and authorization I achieved a good part of the job but now I'm facing a problem that makes the whole usage of keycloak in such a project a question.

So briefly the user authenticates in keycloak and I got the token in spring I extract the Infos and if the user is not in my database (the one related to spring which is different from keycloak database ) I create a new one but now when I'm thinking if a user is deleted from keycloak it will remain in my application database and even the update of users is gonna be difficult.

So my question is should I continue searching for a solution (calling keycloak endpoint from spring is one of them but still thinking about it ) or just go for a JWT implementation .

I chose keycloak cause it's a tested solution and got many features that are easy to use if I needed them in the future but now I got these problems with it.
THANKS for the help !!

Comment: You can use Keycloak custom event listeners. Check [this](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_development/topics/providers.html#providers). So you can react to user events like user created or deleted. And this listener would call your app to for example delete user from your db. One problem with that is that your listener jar has to be deployed together with keycloak which might cause some inconveniences (for example managing your app urls in this listener, deploying new versions of listener to keycloak).

Comment: Yeah, this would help for sure but considering what you mentioned something like this would be a problem cause my colleague who's responsible for deployment doesn't have experience with keycloak and it's gonna be painful for him. 
Do you consider using keycloak a good choice in my case or it's just complicating it?

Comment: You might have to keep users in DB after they are removed from Keycloak, for instance to keep mandatory accounting records for a few years. Other thing, If you don't use JWTs in spring security, you should. [It is easy](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials) and will save a lot of requests to authorization-server. Last, if the reason why you connect spring to user database is to get security data missing from the token, you should look at [keycloak mappers](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api/proxies-keycloak-mapper) to enrich it.

Comment: Actually, I'm making a soft delete (i got a boolean that I make it false instead of real delete ) the problem is if I got a dashboard to display the customers those customers will still be present, if I make a call to keycloak server to get users than send it to the front with a big number of users it's going to be slow.

Comment: As an option, you can add the OpenID Connect layer on top of your existing application and make it an external IdP to the Keycloak. Then add a new identity provider in Keycloak and configure trust between Keycloak and IdP. Every time the user needs to be authenticated they will be redirected to your IdP and after successful auth, they will get back the jwt token signed by the Keycloak. Maybe this scenario will be good for you.

Comment: You can deactivate the user from the keycloak server which is equivalent to soft delete and then hit the keycloak endpoint where you can only fetch the active users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to configure Keycloak with a custom provider (external user database)?

Something like that: https://www.baeldung.com/java-keycloak-custom-user-providers.

This way, your spring services keep complete control over users database.

Comment: If a new user registering keycloak will save it in his database or in the other or is it configurable or do I manage the registration myself and save users in my database directly?

Comment: @Hiroshking are you using keycloak's sdk in your springboot application?